# Microsoft Flow hyperlink not working in Outlook client

Tags: outlook, hyperlink, client, power-automate

Good morning

I'm quite new to MS Flow and I came across an issue that I just can't find a solution for. I created a flow for an approval App in PowerApps and added a Link to the item on the email that is received by the person that needs to approve it. The problem is that the link to the item is not clickable in the Outlook 2016 client. It is in the OWA though, so there must be a setting to fix this (I hope).

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[MS Flow Workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYnzF.png)

[Outlook Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taLjT.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you meant by how to create a link with an href the add the below code in body of your email.

```
<a href="http://www.yoursitelink.com">Click Here for details</A>
```

Click the adavanced options from Send email flow and set 'Is HTML' property value to true.

For more information, please refer to these links:

[How to insert a "Clck Here" in an email?](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/How-to-insert-a-quot-Clck-Here-quot-in-an-email/td-p/10753)

[How do I get flow to stop encoding the ampersand in the href in my anchor tag?](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/How-do-I-get-flow-to-stop-encoding-the-ampersand-in-the-href-in/td-p/97462)

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't add HTML to an approval email when there are multiple approvers that need to approve an item. You have to use the approval email, AFAIK